# Rails Devise / Warden Session in LocalStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, local-storage, warden

I'm developing a web app in Rails 3.2 that's using Devise for authentication.
This works fine in the browser, but when you save it to the homescreen (to make it look more native), I run into my problem.

Everytime you exit the 'app', all cookies and sessions are wiped. So the next time the user opens the app, they need to log in again, and navigate back to where they last were.

I'm looking for an alternative solution to this, possibly using HTML5 LocalStorage or Token Authenticable?

But I just don't know where to start. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue already?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I haven't seen anywhere that's able to do this.

Comment: @Ammar did you find a solution for this?